# Связать вместе input'ы, имеющие разные атрибуты name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть код следующего вида:

```html
<div class="group-options">
    <div class="group-options__item">
        <input type="radio" name="group-1" data-prop="prop1">
        <input type="radio" name="group-1" data-prop="prop1">
        <input type="radio" name="group-1" data-prop="prop1">
        <input type="radio" name="group-1" data-prop="prop1">
    </div>
    <div class="group-options__item">
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" data-prop="prop2">
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" data-prop="prop2">
        <input type="radio" name="group-2" data-prop="prop2">
    </div>
    <div class="group-options__item">
        <input type="radio" name="group-3" data-prop="prop3">
        <input type="radio" name="group-3" data-prop="prop3">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="group-options">
    <div class="group-options__item">
        <input type="radio" name="group-4" data-prop="prop4">
        <input type="radio" name="group-4" data-prop="prop4">
    </div>
    <div class="group-options__item">
        <input type="radio" name="group-5" data-prop="prop5">
        <input type="radio" name="group-5" data-prop="prop5">
        <input type="radio" name="group-5" data-prop="prop5">
    </div>
    <div class="group-options__item">
        <input type="radio" name="group-6" data-prop="prop6">
        <input type="radio" name="group-6" data-prop="prop6">
    </div>
</div>
```

У нас есть несколько блоков `group-options`, содержащих группы радиобаттонов `group-options__item`. У каждого радиобаттона есть дата атрибут `data-prop`, который одинаковый у радиобаттонов, принадлежащих одному `group-options__item` и соответственно атрибут name у них тоже одинаковый, если они принадлежат одному `group-options__item`.

Вопрос такой, можно ли как-то после загрузки страницы, у всех радиобаттонов, принадлежащих к одной группе `group-options`, брать значение `data-prop` у любого радиобаттона в этом блоке и применять его ко всем радиобаттонам в одном `group-options`, чтобы по итогу было вот так?

```html
<div class="group-options">
    <div class="group-options__item">
        <input type="radio" name="group-4" data-prop="prop4">
        <input type="radio" name="group-4" data-prop="prop4">
    </div>
    <div class="group-options__item">
        <input type="radio" name="group-5" data-prop="prop4">
        <input type="radio" name="group-5" data-prop="prop4">
        <input type="radio" name="group-5" data-prop="prop4">
    </div>
    <div class="group-options__item">
        <input type="radio" name="group-6" data-prop="prop4">
        <input type="radio" name="group-6" data-prop="prop4">
    </div>
</div>
```

И второй вопрос, можно ли сделать так, чтобы если выбран какой то радиобаттон в `group-options`, то остальные радиобаттоны, находящихся в разных `group-options__item` принадлежащих одному `group-options` становились не выбранными. То есть сейчас из-за разный атрибутов name в каждом `group-options__item` есть по выбранному радиобаттону, даже если они все и находятся в одном `group-options`, а нужно сделать видимость того, что у них у всех одинаковый атрибут name внутри группы `group-options` и мы можем чекнуть только один радиобаттон в этой группе.

---

пробовал использовать вот такое

```
const group = (() => {
  const groups = element.querySelectorAll('.group-options');
  groups.forEach((element) => {
    let wrapperElem = element.querySelectorAll('.group-options__item');
    wrapperElem.forEach((el) => {
      let elements = el.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]'),
        prop = el.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')[0].dataset.prop;
      elements.forEach((el) => {
        el.setAttribute('data-prop', prop);
      });
    });
  });
})();
```

пока не выходит ничего

Comment: Можно. Можно. Что Вы уже попытались сделать?

Comment: пока не знаю как вообще подступиться к этому

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: пробовал использовать вот такое

`js
const group = (() => {
 const groups = element.querySelectorAll('.group-options');
 groups.forEach((element) => {
  let wrapperElem = element.querySelectorAll('.group-options__item');
  wrapperElem.forEach((el) => {
   let elements = el.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]'),
    prop = el.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')[0].dataset.prop;
   elements.forEach((el) => {
    el.setAttribute('data-prop', prop);
   });
  });
 });
})();
`
то же, о чем пишите вы, только на нативном js, пока не выходит ничего

Comment: "пока не выходит ничего" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: ну моя цель не была достигнута, не заменилось значение дата атрибута у всех радиобаттонов в группе

Comment: Вам нужно изменить значение атрибута или свойства датасета? Это разные вещи.

Comment: то что прислали вы, это то, что требовалось, благодарю!
не могли бы вы помочь со второй частью вопроса?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Ваш ответ не является полном к моему вопросы, поэтому пока отметил его полезным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.group-options')].forEach(function(group) {
  let sDataProp = group.querySelector('[data-prop]').dataset.prop;
  let aItems = [...group.querySelectorAll('[data-prop]')];
  aItems.forEach(function(item) {
    item.dataset.prop = sDataProp;
  });
  group.addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
    aItems.forEach(function(item) {
      if (item != ev.target) {
        item.checked = false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.group-options { box-shadow: 0 0 5px red; } .group-options__item { box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue; } input { margin: 5px 55px; } input::after { content: attr(name) '/' attr(data-prop); position: absolute; margin-left: 17px; }
```

```html
<div class="group-options">
  <div class="group-options__item">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" data-prop="prop1">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" data-prop="prop1">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" data-prop="prop1">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" data-prop="prop1">
  </div>
  <div class="group-options__item">
    <input type="radio" name="group-2" data-prop="prop2">
    <input type="radio" name="group-2" data-prop="prop2">
    <input type="radio" name="group-2" data-prop="prop2">
  </div>
  <div class="group-options__item">
    <input type="radio" name="group-3" data-prop="prop3">
    <input type="radio" name="group-3" data-prop="prop3">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="group-options">
  <div class="group-options__item">
    <input type="radio" name="group-4" data-prop="prop4">
    <input type="radio" name="group-4" data-prop="prop4">
  </div>
  <div class="group-options__item">
    <input type="radio" name="group-5" data-prop="prop5">
    <input type="radio" name="group-5" data-prop="prop5">
    <input type="radio" name="group-5" data-prop="prop5">
  </div>
  <div class="group-options__item">
    <input type="radio" name="group-6" data-prop="prop6">
    <input type="radio" name="group-6" data-prop="prop6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: благодарю, именно то что нужно!

Comment: @Arsenij : пожалуйста. Подробно и понятно описали проблему - получили быстрые и полные ответы. Удачи!

Answer (score 2):

```
const group = (() => {
  const groups = document.querySelectorAll('.group-options');
  groups.forEach(group => {
    const prop = group.querySelector('input[type="radio"]').dataset.prop;
    // or const prop = group.querySelector('input[type="radio"]').getAttribute('data-prop');
    let inputs = group.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
    inputs.forEach(input => input.dataset.prop = prop);
    // or inputs.forEach(input => input.dataset.setAttribute('data-prop', prop);
  });
})();
```